# How to deal with method which throws 7 exceptions

Tags: java

I'm re factoring some code and have come across a method which is throwing 7 exceptions, the method length is approx 20 lines. The method caller wraps this method in a try catch, and just catches the generic Exception. Is there a better way to handle this ? I don't think I should handle each possible exception thrown individually ?

```
try {
setter();
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

    private void setter() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException, XPathExpressionException
    {       
        .....   
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do in case of an exception. If your handling is just printing the stack trace your solution is OK. But you might want to react in a different way depending on the problem.

Just an example:

- an IO problem could mean that you have to retry (in case on network)
- a malformed URL might mean that you have to generate an error message and ask the user to re-enter the data
- and so on

If you do not try to recover from the error, I don't know if it makes sense to catch the exception, print the stack trace and then continue. It might be the same as letting the application crash (and print the exception anyway).

Comment: +1  I agree.  It depends on what each exception is thrown for and how you want to handle them.  Handling all 7 isn't bad if that is what is required.  Perhaps at different abstraction levels different exceptions can be handled....

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to catch a generic exception. (See ["Mistake 2: Catch unspecific exceptions"](https://stackify.com/common-mistakes-handling-java-exception/#mistake2) in [7 Common Mistakes You Should Avoid When Handling Java Exceptions](https://stackify.com/common-mistakes-handling-java-exception/)

> The severity of this mistake depends on the kind of software component
>   you’re implementing and where you catch the exception. It might be ok
>   to catch a *java.lang.Exception* in the *main* method of your Java SE
>   application. But you should prefer to catch specific exceptions, if
>   you’re implementing a library or if you’re working on deeper layers of
>   your application.
>
> That provides several benefits. It allows you to handle each exception
>   class differently and it prevents you from catching exceptions you
>   didn’t expect.

The real code smell here is that the called method is too long, does too many things, and probably violates SRP. As you can see this has ramifications for the called code which now must handle numerous exceptions, i.e. do too many things.

The biggest problem IMO is, as stated in other reviews, that catching a generic exception has the unintended consequence of possibly catching other exceptions that are not one of those that are declared, and consequently handling them in an unintended way.

Answer (score 0):

`throws` in method declaration means that this method throws that exceptions, but does not handle them by itself.

If a method may throw an exception that it does not handle, it must specify this so that callers can handle that exception.

This is necessary for all exceptions, except `Error` or `RuntimeException`, or any of their derivatives. All other exceptions must be declared in the `throws` clause. If they are not, a compile-time error will (or may, I'm not sure) be generated.

Bottom line, if you try to throw non-listed exception, compiler will not compile. If you list all necessary exceptions, users of the class will be forced to use `try catch` blocks.

Comment: That's a nice description of checked exceptions, but it doesn't seem to address the question?